# what happen to an unlocked unique_lock when condition_variable::wait() is called?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here's an sample code on a C++ reference website

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

void print_id(int id) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    while (!ready) {
        lck.unlock(); // by curiosity I unlock the lck
        cv.wait(lck);
    }
    std::cout << "thread " << id << '\n';
}

void go() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    ready = true;
    lck.unlock();
    cv.notify_all();
}

int main() {
    std::thread threads[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        threads[i] = std::thread(print_id, i);
    go();
    for (auto &th : threads)
        th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

If I don't unlock the unique_lock before calling wait(), everything works normally. Like:

```
thread 9
thread 1
thread 2
thread 3
thread 4
thread 5
thread 6
thread 7
thread 8
thread 0
```

I've been told that

> At the moment of blocking the thread, the function(`wait()`) automatically calls lck.unlock(), allowing other locked threads to continue.

So I wonder what if I unlock unique_lock before wait() is called.After I did that, the program behaved weirdly, only one or two threads complete their job(print the "thread X" message), other threads seem to be blocked (by the unique_lock?) forever.

What happened to those unique_locks? Or it's just another undefined behavior of c++ that calling unlock() before wait()?

Thanks!

Comment: "So I wonder what if I unlock unique_lock before wait() is called." Why?

Comment: "After I did that, the program behaved weirdly" - pretty much a definition of Undefined Behaviour, right there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in documentation of [std::condition_variable::wait()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)

> Calling this function if lock.mutex() is not locked by the current thread is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried that out of curiosity while didn't read the reference carefully enough :( But why the standard don't allow to do so? Is it suggesting that this behavior is unsafe for data?

Comment: @XaL whole purpose of condition variable is to allow a thread to unlock a mutex and get into sleep state **atomically** And do reverse action as well. So your question is similar to: "why beer opener does not work without beer?"